# Pushing data from one form to another using javascript or jquery through the get

Tags: javascript, php, html, magento, get

I have an initial sign up box for email on my website build in php. I'm using magento so I can not simply echo the variable from the get into the email field on the next page. That's the only way i'm currently use to doing this.

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('email_preferences') ?>" method="get" id="newsletter-validate-detail" class="footerNewsletter">
    <label for="newsletter" class="footerHeads"><?php echo $this->__('Connect With US') ?></label>
    <div class="inputTextContainer">
        <input name="email" type="text" id="newsletter" placeholder="<?php echo $this->__('enter email for specials and updates!') ?>"
               title="<?php echo $this->__('Enter email for specials and updates!') ?>" class="required-entry validate-email">
        <i class="icon-mail"></i>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="source" value="nt" />
    <button type="submit" class="button" style="display:none;" title="<?php echo $this->__('Subscribe') ?>"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Subscribe') ?></span></span></button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var newsletterSubscriberFormDetail = new VarienForm('newsletter-validate-detail');
//]]>
</script>
```

The second page would have a standard input box like so:

```
<input type="text" name="email" size="40" maxlength="100" value=""/>
```

I know in php I could use the value and echo $email.

I was thinking in javascript i could use something like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("email").innerhtml = window.location.search;
</script>
```

I'm not sure how to use `document.write` to fill in the email input though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), it will make life much easier. Assuming your page URL is something like this: `www.example.com/page.php?email=me@email.com`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('input[name="email"]').val(window.location.search.replace('?email=', ''));
});
</script>
```

If you are accessing `www.example.com/page.php?email=you@domain.com` then the "name" input field would get the value "you@domain.com".

Sample fidde: https://jsfiddle.net/f8817t4q/ (had to replace `window.location.search` with a static string for demonstration purposes, though).

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Comment: I have more of a dynamic link after the .com. how do i cut that off.. anything after the .com.  &source=nt

Comment: Something do do with these second quotes i suppose?  ('?email=', '')

Comment: Actually i got a percentage sign instead of the @ too. Also i'm not sure where that 40 came from.. ugghh.. sorryy.. This is currently what it looks like...   bob.thompson%40company.com&source=nt

Comment: Any change you can still help me with this last part?

Comment: Add .replace('%40', '@') after .replace('?email=', '')

Comment: That solved everything and i did a replace on the last part of the string with a blank ""